# if($_GET['page']) Error

Tags: php

Hello i have this script.

```
if($_GET['page']) {
        if (isset($_GET['page']))
        $id = $db->escape_string($_GET['page']);
        if ($usersquery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM padges WHERE id ='$id' LIMIT 1"))
        $content = $usersquery->fetch_assoc();
    }
    if(!$_GET['page']) {
        if (isset($_GET['page']))
        $id = $db->escape_string($_GET['page']);
        if ($usersquery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM padges WHERE ID ='10' LIMIT 1"))
        $content = $usersquery->fetch_assoc();
    }
```

If i go to http://127.0.0.1/?page=10 i have no error.
But if i go to http://127.0.0.1 i get this error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in /sites/ergotherapiewalcheren.nl/www/index.php on line 6 Notice: Undefined index: page in /sites/ergotherapiewalcheren.nl/www/index.php on line 12
```

How can i fix this error?

Tom Lammers

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['page']))` should check to see if `page` has been passed in.

Comment: Read about [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

The first check should not be needed, remove:

```
if($_GET['page']) {
```

As you are already checking if it's set:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
```

Comment: Tnx I have if (! $ _ GET ['page']) {delete, only now I get this error Notice: Undefined variable: id in /sites/ergotherapiewalcheren.nl/www/index.php on line 9

Comment: instead of using an if to check if it's set and another if to check if it's not set,  use if/else.

Comment: Can you make it for my i don´t understand it